# Why is Ion Exchange Chromatography done in a column?

Tags: chromatography

It seems like the idea of Ion Exchange Chromatography is to get a maximum amount of exposure of your gel to your solution. It seems like overhead stirring and a gel bed would be more likely to be successful here.

Comment: It seems like you are focussing on the ion exchange part and ignoring the chromatography.

Comment: Yes, with a solid ion-exchange bead sitting in solution, you are doing an equilibrium experiment. You do not have a true equilibrium condition in a chromatography column.

Comment: [Chromatography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatography?wprov=sfla1)  is a dynamic separation technique, done on columns or planes. Usage of ion-exchange resin is just circumstance.  There is no separation of analytes or substances in the static gel bed scenario, just different distribution constants.

Comment: Do you bath you car's engine with gas, or do you prefer, for practical reasons, to put the gas station's nozzle to this funnel shaped entry to channel the gas into a the tank? (irony!)